# ImportHtml/IMPORTXML in Excel/Sheets - load next index after content of variable size

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, xml, import, google-spreadsheets

I'm using functions such as ImportHtml to import tabular data into Google Sheets. Each table has the same headers but contains an unknown number of rows. I need each table from a list of URLs to appear below the last with each heading aligned under the same columns.

I would simply input a list of URLs contains tables and each would be populated inside the spreadsheet one below each other depending on how many URLs I supply in the range.

#### The data should look like this:

[image: what I want to achieve]

My difficulty is that I don't know which function(s) I need to use.

- Basically I need to use ImportHtml to insert the data, find the size
  of the table so that the next URL in column A comes immediately after
  the end of the previous table.
- Then, in column A, I simply increment
  the index to grab the next URL from column I.
- Now I can insert an
  =ImportHtml function in column D using the URL from column A (of course, I could simply take the next index from column I but it's
  helpful to see the URL next to the data).

It's trivial enough to let    column A know when the data is finished    in rows D-F then take the    next indexed URL but I don't see a way    to fill down the ImportHtml    function through column D as it fails    when it would overwrite data    even if that data is a inactive    ImportHtml.

I keep running into    circular calculation issues    probably because I'm using incorrect    hacky methods instead of the    most efficient function.

A workaround would be to leave a buffer of, say, 500 cells under each call but the tables could be of any length from 2-2000 rows so this doesn't work. It also makes it difficult if the number of URLs in the range changes for any reason.

#### What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You might be creeping into the realms of scripting for this. I can't think of any way to have a cell determine it's content based on what's above it without `IMPORTHTML` complaining with a `REF#` error like you've already run into.

Comment: Wow, thanks, have to say I'm surprised though - compared to some of the things I've done with simple spreadsheet formulae, this is incredibly basic. I really hoped there would be a simple way of having an "after-import buffer" of some kind. The only other option would be maybe to populate a new sheet? Or to have the tables horizontally since they are all of fixed width. Not sure...

Comment: The more I think about it, absent some way to ImportHtml into some other cell, the most workable method is the incredibly ugly horizontal span of imported tables because this is the only way I avoid having each ImportHtml function treading on the toes of the ones beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The answer was more obvious that I thought!

Just use ArrayFormula:

```
{ImportHtml(I1,"table",1);ImportHtml(I2,"table",1);ImportHtml(I3,"table",1);ImportHtml(I4,"table",1);ImportHtml(I5,"table",1);ImportHtml(I6,"table",1);ImportHtml(I7,"table",1);ImportHtml(I8,"table",1);ImportHtml(I9,"table",1);ImportHtml(I10,"table",1)}
```

or:

```
=ArrayFormula({ImportHtml(I1,"table",1);ImportHtml(I2,"table",1);ImportHtml(I3,"table",1);ImportHtml(I4,"table",1);ImportHtml(I5,"table",1);ImportHtml(I6,"table",1);ImportHtml(I7,"table",1);ImportHtml(I8,"table",1);ImportHtml(I9,"table",1);ImportHtml(I10,"table",1)})
```

From [Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275):

> ### ARRAYFORMULA
>
> Enables the display of values returned from an array
>   formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array
>   functions with arrays.
>
> #### Sample Usage
>
> *ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A1:A10>5, A1:A10, 0)))*
>
> *ARRAYFORMULA(A1:C1+A2:C2)*
>
> #### Syntax
>
> *ARRAYFORMULA(array_formula)*
>
> **array_formula** - A range, mathematical expression using one cell range
>   or multiple ranges of the same size, or a function that returns a
>   result greater than one cell. Notes Many array formulas will be
>   automatically expanded into neighboring cells, obviating the explicit
>   use of *ARRAYFORMULA*.
>
> Pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter while editing a formula will automatically
>   add *ARRAYFORMULA(* to the beginning of the formula.

See also [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).